# cascading SQL with not exist

Tags: sql, select, cascade

i have an SQL like this:

```
SELECT distinct * 
FROM LETTRE_VOIT_TEMP where NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM LETTRE_VOIT_FINAL lv
  where lv.NOID        = LETTRE_VOIT_TEMP.NOID 
  AND lv.CODE_DEST   = LETTRE_VOIT_TEMP.CODE_DEST 
  AND lv.CODE_CLIENT = LETTRE_VOIT_TEMP.CODE_CLIENT 
  AND (LETTRE_VOIT_TEMP.NO_ORDRE_CUMMUL  IS NULL OR lv.NO_ORDRE_CUMMUL = LETTRE_VOIT_TEMP.NO_ORDRE_CUMMUL) 
  AND (LETTRE_VOIT_TEMP.DATE_CLOTURE     IS NULL OR lv.DATE_CLOTURE     = LETTRE_VOIT_TEMP.DATE_CLOTURE)
  AND (LETTRE_VOIT_TEMP.DATE_CLOTUR_REEL IS NULL OR lv.DATE_CLOTUR_REEL =  LETTRE_VOIT_TEMP.DATE_CLOTUR_REEL)

)
```

it work well, but the problem is when the table LETTRE_VOIT_FINAL content many data, then it will slow the request.

so i change like this :

```
SELECT distinct * 
FROM LETTRE_VOIT_TEMP where NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM LETTRE_VOIT_FINAL lv
  where lv.NOID        = LETTRE_VOIT_TEMP.NOID 
  AND lv.CODE_DEST   = LETTRE_VOIT_TEMP.CODE_DEST 
  AND lv.CODE_CLIENT = LETTRE_VOIT_TEMP.CODE_CLIENT 
  AND (LETTRE_VOIT_TEMP.NO_ORDRE_CUMMUL  IS NULL OR lv.NO_ORDRE_CUMMUL = LETTRE_VOIT_TEMP.NO_ORDRE_CUMMUL) 
  AND (LETTRE_VOIT_TEMP.DATE_CLOTURE     IS NULL OR lv.DATE_CLOTURE     = LETTRE_VOIT_TEMP.DATE_CLOTURE)
  AND (LETTRE_VOIT_TEMP.DATE_CLOTUR_REEL IS NULL OR lv.DATE_CLOTUR_REEL =  LETTRE_VOIT_TEMP.DATE_CLOTUR_REEL)
  --AND lv.date_cloture between DATEADD(dd, -4, GETDATE()) and DATEADD(dd, +4, GETDATE())
  AND lv.DATE_CLOTUR_REEL = @DATE_CLOTUR_REEL
)
```

it not work as i expected.

i want to select first all LETTRE_VOIT_FINAL WHERE DATE_CLOTUR_REEL = @DATE_CLOTUR_REEL and then i compare with LETTRE_VOIT_TEMP.

how can i do that ?

Answer (score 0):

put it in a subquery. The subquery will filter it first then the outer query will do your comparison.

```
SELECT distinct * 
FROM LETTRE_VOIT_TEMP where NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM (
       SELECT *
        FROM LETTRE_VOIT_FINAL 
       WHERE lv.DATE_CLOTUR_REEL = @DATE_CLOTUR_REEL
       ) lv    
  where lv.NOID        = LETTRE_VOIT_TEMP.NOID 
  AND lv.CODE_DEST   = LETTRE_VOIT_TEMP.CODE_DEST 
  AND lv.CODE_CLIENT = LETTRE_VOIT_TEMP.CODE_CLIENT 
  AND (LETTRE_VOIT_TEMP.NO_ORDRE_CUMMUL  IS NULL OR lv.NO_ORDRE_CUMMUL = LETTRE_VOIT_TEMP.NO_ORDRE_CUMMUL) 
  AND (LETTRE_VOIT_TEMP.DATE_CLOTURE     IS NULL OR lv.DATE_CLOTURE     = LETTRE_VOIT_TEMP.DATE_CLOTURE)
  AND (LETTRE_VOIT_TEMP.DATE_CLOTUR_REEL IS NULL OR lv.DATE_CLOTUR_REEL =  LETTRE_VOIT_TEMP.DATE_CLOTUR_REEL)
  --AND lv.date_cloture between DATEADD(dd, -4, GETDATE()) and DATEADD(dd, +4, GETDATE())
  )
```